# Where can I get non-standard tennis net?

Tags: tennis

I've just bought a new tennis net and discovered that it's 42 feet long which I assume is the standard. I've also just discovered that my poles are 39 feet apart so the net is too long to fit between the poles. Do shorter tennis nets exist and where do you get them from?

Edit:

> Typically the net standards are placed 3 feet outside the outer lines
>   of the doubles court, making the net length a total of 42 feet from
>   pole to pole.

It appears that the standards on my court are much closer to the outer lines.

Comment: I managed to find 38', 40' and 42' on Amazon.com so have ordered the 38' one which should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the court was lined for adults, then the posts are in the wrong position, and I don't think you'll be able to find a net to accommodate their incorrect position.

If the court was lined for children, then you can use one of the 18 feet or 10 feet nets here http://www.tennis-warehouse.com/catpage-COURTEQT.html, and not use your posts.

Measure the distance between the singles sidelines (27 feet), the doubles sidelines (36 feet) and the length of the court (78 feet).  Take all measurements to the outside of the line.  If the measurements are as I provide, then you have an adult court, and should have the net posts re-installed in their correct position.